# Initializing a variable on loop.first in jinja2 worked in version 2.8, but not in version 2.9.5

Tags: jinja2, pyramid

I was applying the following logic in jinja2 version 2.8 and the code was working as expected:

```
{%- for x in timeline -%}
  {%- if loop.first -%}
    {%- set N = 0 -%}
    ...do something with N...
  {%- else -%}
    {%- if prevActionType != "some string" -%}
      {%- set N = N + 1 -%}
      ...do something with N...
    {%- endif -%}
  {%- endif -%}
  {%- set prevActionType = x.actionType -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```

As can be seen, I need to track `N` separately from the loop iteration number.

I have upgraded jinja2 to version 2.9.5 and now I get the following error:

```
...
{%- set N = N + 1 -%}
UndefinedError: 'N' is undefined
```

It seems to me, if the `timeline` data has 1 or more rows, `N` will always be initialized to the value 0. According to jinja2 docs, `if` statements do not introduce new scope. My entire code block only has one `for` loop and `N` is only used inside this `for` loop.

The underlying python version is 2.7.x.   Why this error after upgrading?

Comment: Did you review the [changelog](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/changelog/#version-2-9-5)? Also why not `set N = 0` outside the `for` loop, then increment it just before the `endfor`?  Also why not use logic on the value of `N` instead of `loop.first`?

Comment: Yes, reviewed changelog...some possible changes that may affect this issue, but not enough details to know for certain.  In jinja2, variables go out of scope when moving outside of for loops, so I was trying to keep all things to do with variables inside the loop...well, inside the loop.  Using loop.first is a way of keeping the initialization of N completely inside the loop.